# Using gizmos to illustrate the sorting process

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

The codes below generate 10000cubes(using gizmos). I'm stuck on how to further expand the code and using gizmos to illustrate the sorting process(movement of the cubes when mouse button is click), appreciate if can give me some hint on how to do it.
using UnityEngine;

```
 public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour
{
int x;
int y;
int z;

int[,] array1 = new int[100, 100];
int temp;

void Start()
{



    for (x = 0; x < 100; x++)

    {
        for (y = 0; y < 100; y++)
        {
            array1[x, y] = Random.Range(0, 2);

            Debug.Log(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", x, y, array1[x, y]));

        }
    }


}
void OnDrawGizmos()
{
    
    for (x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        for (y = 0; y < 100; y++)
        {
            Vector2 pos1 = new Vector2(0 + x, 0 + y);
            Gizmos.DrawCube(pos1, transform.position);
            Gizmos.color = (array1[x, y] == 1) ? Color.black : Color.white;
        }
    }
}
void OnMouseDown()
{
    for (z = 0; z < 100; z++)
    {
        for (x = 0; x < 100; x++)
        {
            for (y = 0; y < 100-z; y++)
            {
                if (array1[x, y] > array1[x, y + 1])
                    temp = array1[x, y];
                array1[x + 1, y] = array1[x, y];
                array1[x, y] = temp;

            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1.Possible Solution

I provide an answer in this part, and suggest better alternatives below.

The problem with your code is that the sorting happens synchronously, within one frame. What you can do is move the sorting code to Update, and sort a little between each frame. This will let the Gizmos call draw the correct state.

## 2.Use Progress Bar instead

You may use [EditorUtility.DisplayProgressBar](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorUtility.DisplayProgressBar.html) to display a progress bar in the Editor. Since you're using Gizmos which don't show up in the Build, this solution assumes you're working in the Editor.

## 3.Use Compute Buffers

CatLikeCoding has this fantastic article on using [Compute Shaders to draw a Graph in high resolution](https://catlikecoding.com/unity/tutorials/basics/compute-shaders/). You can follow it and draw your sorting progress in a very high resolution. Furthermore, this will work in both editor and runtime.